# Get rid of ${{\rm{a}} \over {\rm{0}}}$ in a limit.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, rational-functions

I'm trying to solve this limit but I can't figure out how to get rid of the undefined form.
$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt x }} - {1 \over {\sqrt {{x^2} + x} }}} \right)  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} \left( {{{\sqrt {{x^2} + x}  - \sqrt x } \over {\sqrt {{x^3} + {x^2}} }}} \right) \cr} $$
$$\eqalign{
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} \left( {{{{x^2}} \over {\left( {\sqrt {{x^3} + {x^2}} } \right)\left( {\sqrt {{x^2} + x}  + \sqrt x } \right)}}} \right)  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} \left( {{{{x^2}} \over {\left( {x\sqrt {x + 1} } \right)\left( {x\sqrt {x + 1}  + x\sqrt {{1 \over x}} } \right)}}} \right) \cr} $$
$$ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} \left( {{x \over {\left( {(x + 1) + \sqrt {1 + {1 \over x}} } \right)}}} \right)$$

Now what?

Comment: The denominator tends to $\infty$ while the numerator tends to $0$.

Comment: In fact your answer is also correct. Note that in your last step, the denominator goes to $\infty$ while the numerator goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the conjugate of the denominator in problems like this always helps:
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x}} \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x} - \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2 + x}} \\
= & \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + x} - \sqrt{x})\color{red}{(\sqrt{x^2 + x} + \sqrt{x})}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2 + x}\color{red}{(\sqrt{x^2 + x} + \sqrt{x})}} \\
= & \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2 + x}(\sqrt{x^2 + x} + \sqrt{x})} \\
= & \frac{x^{1/2}}{\sqrt{x + 1}(\sqrt{x + 1} + 1)} \to 0
\end{align}
as $x \to 0+$.